# how to give two different states in css?

Tags: html, css

I have this problem in css where i have two different states in css for example

```
#koolbutton .active {

   color: #fff

}

#koolbutton{

  color: #ccc   //not active

}
```

When i try this html

```
<button id ="koolbutton" class="active">
```

It gives me the the normal grey koolbutton not the active one which is white! thanks

Comment: The problem is the space between `#koolbutton` and `.active`. The selector you have used is looking for an element with the class `active`, that is contained somewhere inside another element with the id `koolbutton`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to omit the space between `#koolbutton` and `.active`.

```css
#koolbutton { /*not active*/ }
#koolbutton.active { /*active*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one also;

```
#koolbutton:active {
   color: #fff; //when user click the button
}
#koolbutton{
  color: #ccc; //normal display of button
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/2wr9P/)*** is the working Live Demo.

Comment: you should explain what this does as it isn't exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your first selector:

```css
#koolbutton .active
```

Since there is a space between the id and class selector, this applies to every element with a class of `active` and an ancestor with an id of `koolbutton`. What you want is to select every element with a class of `active` **and** an id of `koolbutton`:

```css
#koolbutton.active
```

Although the order of your selectors doesn't matter due to [CSS Specificity rules](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/), in terms of creating more maintainable CSS I would recommend you put the default styles first, followed by any variations to that style:

```css
#koolbutton { /* default styles */ }
#koolbutton.active { /* .active styles */ }
#koolbutton.foo { /* Another class styles */ }
```

If you are really wanting to style active/focus states, you should probably look at the `:focus` and `:active` pseudo selectors.